# Can two functions have identical second derivatives and the same lateral limits?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

I'm looking for two not identical functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ on $(a,b)$ (to simplify, assume that $a = 0$ and $b = 1$) where:

1) The second derivatives are the same on $(a,b)$, that is, $f''(x) = g''(x)$;

2) $lim_{x \to a^{+}} f(x) = lim_{x \to a^{+}} g(x) = f(a) = g(a)$

3) $lim_{x \to b^{-}} f(x) = lim_{x \to b^{-}} g(x) = f(b) = g(b)$

I'm not sure but are the above-mentioned conditions related to the uniqueness of second order differential equations, i.e., $f(x) = g(x)$?

Comment: A soft remark: So far, it does not seem possible. I'll see if I can derive a general result later or likely someone else will provide one.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f^{\prime\prime}(x)=g^{\prime\prime}(x)$ implies $f^\prime(x)=g^\prime(x)+c$ for some constant $c$, and again, the last implies $f(x)=g(x)+cx+d$  for some constant $d$.

Using your hypothesis (2) and (3) you can get de values of $c$ and $d$.

Comment: In fact, from (2) and (3) we have $c = d = 0$ (due to $a \neq b$) and thus, $f(x) = g(x)$.